# What kind of exception it must be? JUnit test Assertion error

Tags: java, exception, junit, assert

Please help me with understanding this case. I've been studying Java a while ago and I do not understand a lot of moments. My program has a Integer List input. It converts this list to 2d array and build inside of array a saw triangle like /\ with the smallest number at the top and from left to right order and returns it back. Also I need to create a new class for handling errors

```
private static int[] countSize(int listSize){
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    for(int x=1, y=0; x+y<=listSize; x=x+y, y++, rows++);
    columns = 2*rows-1;
    return new int[] { rows, columns };
}


private static int[][] buildTriangle(List<Integer> list) throws myException{
    if(!list.isEmpty()&&!list.contains(null)&&(list.size()<Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8))
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> workList = new ArrayList<>();
        workList.addAll(list);
        Collections.sort(workList);
        int[] sizes = countSize(list.size());
        int[][] resArray = new int[sizes[0]][sizes[1]];

       //...sort logic...

        System.out.println();
            for(int x=0; x<sizes[0]; x++) {
                for (int y=0; y<sizes[1]; y++)
                    System.out.print("\t" + resArray[x][y] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }

        return resArray;
    }
    else throw new myException("Input is incorrect");
    }

public int[][] buildPyramid(List<Integer> input) {
    try{
        return buildTriangle(input);
    } catch (myException e) {
        throw new myException();
    }
}
```

and exceptions handling class

```
public class myException extends RuntimeException {
    public myException(String message) {
    super(message);}
}
```

when x is 256 (or some other number like 10000) or bigger JUnit test shows an assertion error because it waiting for an exception. I don't understand what kind of exception can be caused by such data? I'm also glad to hear comments on the code

Here is a reslt for a 7 input elements

> 0   0   0   1   0   0   0 
>     0   0   2   0   3   0   0 
>     0   4   0   5   0   6   0 
>     7   0   0   0   0   0   0

Comment: Your test case is 'under the correct circumstances, my exception is thrown' ; however, you don't create those circumstances. Call the method with an empty list or one that is too full, or contains `null`, for it to be a valid test case.

Comment: @daniu the code of this test can not be changed. I need my program to throw an exception when running this test. I don't understand why this test waiting for an exception as result

Comment: Where does the test come from then? A test is meant to verify specifications, if you're given a test you have to pass, you need to be given the specification as well. If this is an exercise, maybe you missed something in the text.

Comment: @daniu yes, it is an excercise. 
"Builds a pyramid with sorted values (with minumum value at the top line and maximum at the bottom, from left to right). All vacant positions in the array are zeros.
     * param  input to be used in the pyramid
     * return 2d array with pyramid inside
     * throws {@link myException} if the pyramid cannot be build with given input" . 

This test is one of a set of tests that check my solution, but all of them are OK (except this)

Comment: Why do you expect it to throw an exception? You throw an exception if your list is empty or contains null or its size is >2147483639, none of which are true

Comment: @mattfreake This test was not written by me. I wrote a program that must pass these tests successfully. The program runs on all tests except this. if you look at its specification, then you will see it is successful if the program throws an exception. But my program is working fine with this data set and I do not understand what the test writer meant

Comment: If the test is correct, then your program needs to throw an exception when it gets a list with a size of 256. So you'd need to change the condition which currently says (list.size()<Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8))

Comment: The result you posted is not a valid pyramid, it's missing three numbers to have a proper base. That case is supposed to throw an exception.

Comment: @daniu yeah i think it is the problem, thank you. i do not have a proper base checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that 'able to build pyramid' means 'the base needs to be filled'. This is the case for 1, 3, 6, 10, and so on.

Figure out a pattern to that series, and check if the list you're given fits ;otherwise throw the exception.

Here's a list that doesn't fit : { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.

Output array :

> 00100
>
> 02340
>
> 56700

See that's not a proper pyramid?

Comment: well, I'll try to ask my question differently. Another tests with input like _List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(4, 1, 7, 4, 0, 5 ...)_ are wokrs fine and waiting for an  2d array as a result. But test with input like in main question, which fill the input List through the "for" loop are waiting for an exception. My program doesn't pass this test because it wors with this input correctly and returns an array

Comment: I'm talking about the size of the list, not the contents. Please edit the question to provide the output of your function for an input list with 7 elements. I added one to the answer.

Comment: added the result that I get when doing your input of 7 digits. program works right with any size of the list including list from a problem test. maybe it waits for an exception because resulted 2d array is too big?